# How can I get id/text of all selected radiobuttons in a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am building a quiz application.
I have a recyclerview which holds multiple cards, each containing many radiobuttons.
I have a submit button at the end of recyclerview. When a user clicks on submit he gets his scores on how he fared in the quiz.
One approach I thought was to check the selected radiobutton in each view individually and compare its string with the correct answer.
How to implement this functionality?

**Screenshots from my app:**
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKUdT.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5sYZ.png)

Comment: Please provide your code. Both `xml` and `java` are required to understand and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add click listener to each radio button and on click save selected item text into the object which is present inside arraylist. These are done inside onBindViewHolder

```
 RadioButton.OnClickListener onClickListener= new RadioButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton radioButton= (RadioButton) v;
            SampleObject sampleObject=arrayList.get(i);
            sampleObject.setAnswer(radioButton.getText().toString());

        }
    };
    sampleViewHolder.r1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    sampleViewHolder.r2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    sampleViewHolder.r3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    sampleViewHolder.r4.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```